# Python regular expression extract the text between two values

Tags: python, xml, regex, parsing

what a regular expression to extract the text between two values?

in:

```
<office:annotation office:name="__Annotation__45582_97049284">
</office:annotation>
    case 1 there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols
<office:annotation-end office:name="__Annotation__45582_97049284"/>

<office:annotation office:name="__Annotation__19324994_2345354">
</office:annotation>
    case 2there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols
<office:annotation-end office:name="__Annotation__19324994_2345354"/>
```

out:

```
list = [
'case 1 there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols',
'case 2 there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols',
]
```

Comment: You'll be better off using an xml parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use an XML parser, if you want a regex solution then try the below,

```
>>> str = """<office:annotation office:name="__Annotation__45582_97049284">
... </office:annotation>
...     case 1 there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols
... <office:annotation-end office:name="__Annotation__45582_97049284"/>
... 
... <office:annotation office:name="__Annotation__19324994_2345354">
... </office:annotation>
...     case 2there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols
... <office:annotation-end office:name="__Annotation__19324994_2345354"/>"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'<\/office:annotation>\s*(.*)(?=\n<office:annotation-end)', str)
>>> m
['case 1 there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols', 'case 2there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols']
```

OR

A better regex would be,

```
<\/office:annotation>([\w\W\s]*?)(?=\n?<office:annotation-end)
```

Comment: strange, it seems that I need, but your example returns an empty list

Comment: does not correct for the same line without formatting (spaces, the line breaks) http://regex101.com/r/rK2hC3/1

Comment: Thank you very much it's work! (it is not I have set you a minus)

Comment: It may look like it works, but it doesn't. [It can't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761). It will break at the slightest change to your input.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a namespaced XML document, you'll have to deal with those namespaces when selecting nodes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714466/1599111) for details.

Here's how you would parse it using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) and `xpath` expressions:

**data.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<document xmlns:office="http://www.example.org/office">

    <office:annotation office:name="__Annotation__45582_97049284">
    </office:annotation>
        case 1 there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols
    <office:annotation-end office:name="__Annotation__45582_97049284"/>

    <office:annotation office:name="__Annotation__19324994_2345354">
    </office:annotation>
        case 2there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols
    <office:annotation-end office:name="__Annotation__19324994_2345354"/>

</document>
```

**parse.py**

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
nsmap = root.nsmap

annotations = root.xpath('//office:annotation', namespaces=nsmap)

comments = []
for annotation in annotations:
    comment = annotation.tail.strip()
    comments.append(comment)

print comments
```

Output:

```
['case 1 there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols',
 'case 2there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'</.+>\s*(.+)\s*<.+>')
>>> matched = re.findall(regex, text)
>>> print(matched)
['case 1 there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols', 'case 2there can be an arbitrary text with any symbols']
```

Edit: There we go. Bah.. these edit points.