# How to Import XML into Spreadsheet with Python?

Tags: python, xml, import, xlsx, xlsxwriter

As the title suggests, how can I import a XML file into Spreadsheet with Python. I need for documenting High Level Router Configurations in a Spreadsheet format.

I have been using xlsxwriter to create spreadsheet etc, but have no idea how to put xml files into spreadsheet

Comment: I would suggest you look into converting xml into csv:
[xmlutils package](https://github.com/knadh/xmlutils.py) and
[similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714038/xml-to-csv-in-python)

Comment: You may refer to the answer under question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007874/how-to-import-an-xml-file-into-an-excel-xls-file-template-using-python
there they suggest to use pandas and BeautifulSoup